# KDE System Tray locks UI while redrawing

Tags: xorg, kde, system-tray

KDE 4.8.2

Whenever a notification is displayed or the KDE panel attempts to change the contents of the system tray my system's UI locks up because X is using 100% CPU.

This occurs both when Desktop Effects are enabled and disabled, and it seems to be linked to the Panel System Tray (full panel without system Tray = fine, empty panel with system tray = lock).

Any idea what could be going wrong, or does anyone have a good idea on how to begin troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing this back from the dead.  It seems to have been related to either an issue with NVidia drivers or (more likely) a failing video card.

There's some pointers in the ArchLinux wiki to use `nvidia-settings -a InitialPixmapPlacement=2` which alleviated my issues a little bit, but they always seemed to come back.

Hope this helps.